# Spring Boot Login Redirect 302 Losing HTTPS

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, https

Upon login attempt in a SpringBoot app using custom login page, the webapp automatically switches from HTTPS to HTTP. I want to allow both, but it shouldn't switch out of HTTPS automatically if it was already there. See Chrome log here:

-- General

- Request URL:https://example.com/login
- Request Method:POST
- Status Code:302

-- Response Headers:

- location:http://example.com/

I'm using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, my configure(HttpSecurity http):

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/version*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
.and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
```

My /login page is quite simple:

```
<form method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
     <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
     <input type="text" name="username">
     <input type="password" name="password">
     <input id="signInBtn" type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Anyone know how I can fix the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using the following spring config:

`security.require-ssl=true`

It will force HTTPS despite a spring boot app running on port 8080.